# php session and cookies

Tags: php, session, cookies

I want to have sessions persist the browser closing
So I used

```
session_set_cookie_params(86400 * 60, '/', 'my.domain.com', true, true);
```

to send a persistent cookie to the client (also with the secure flag as this is a SSL site)
which is valid for 2 months.
However, I see that after x minutes of inactivity the session variables are cleared on the server.
How can I avoid that? Essentially, I want the session variables to be stored until the cookie
becomes invalid

Thanks

Comment: "I want to have sessions persist the browser closing" -- Actually that's the implementation you have thought of.  What are you actually trying to do?  If you want to have the user stay logged in, i.e. a "remember me" type functionality, then best to store a separate, persistent cookie with the (encrypted) authentication details, and re-apply them in the new session.  Sessions are not meant to be persistent, that's why non-persistent cookies are also called session cookies.

Comment: Hi, actually the functionality I am looking for is the remember me

Answer (score 1):

Set the [session.gc_maxlifetime configuration property](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime).

The documentation is rather sparse when it comes to acceptable values for it, but I wouldn't want to go as high as two months.

You'd usually be better off storing the important data in a database, and adding it to a session when one is created with a *remember me* cookie.

Leave sessions for actual sessions.

Answer (score 1):

With sessions you are looking at two things. The time until garbage collection cleans up the session on the server, and the time until the cookie expires.

You only changed the cookie expiration, the session will still get cleaned up. However extending the session is not a great way to solve this. Your code could change and you may end up with users having a broken session. You may need to use some sort of shared session storage like memcached that will delete the storage after a certain max time anyway.

So the way to solve this is to generate a unique one time cookie that can be used as an alternative login key. This key will allow a user to login similar to a username/password. Once its used, a new one gets regenerated.

Comment: very nice approach. I will consider this

Answer (score 0):

Session variables will persist as commented below, but unless you change their default behavior, they expire when the session ends (i.e. when the browser is closed).

For what you're trying to accomplish, you should store your values in `$_COOKIE` variables, not `$_SESSION` variables.

See this article: http://buildinternet.com/2010/07/when-to-use-_session-vs-_cookie/

Comment: Session variables will work as long as the PHPSESSID cookie is persistent (and the session hasn't been GCed between visits).  PHP doesn't actually know when the browser's closed; if another instance of the browser comes along and hands it that same cookie, it's none the wiser.

Comment: Right, but for what the user is trying to accomplish, I don't believe this method is ideal since he wants them to persist.

Comment: @AdamD I agree - this sounds like a much better use case for regular cookies. Leave sessions to what they're meant for - a single browsing session.

Comment: It's definitely not ideal for waiting a couple months, unless he's willing to tell PHP not to destroy sessions at all (which causes a whole other set of problems).  But cookie variables have problems too -- a high one on the list being, they're controlled by the user (whereas session variables are under the server's control).  If you set critical variables in a cookie, you better have some way to verify them.  And if they're meant to be private, possibly encrypt them and pass the entire session as a base64-encoded blob.  It's not gonna be pretty either way.

Comment: @cHao - right but the user here hasn't specified any security expectations. And to be honest, if you have something that is SO secure, then you shouldn't be storing it for 2 months in the first place...

Comment: Yeah, people don't think about security when they should.  :)  *Cookies are user input*, and should be treated at least as skeptically as any form field or query string param.  Probably more so, considering how rarely they ever get such attention.  What's more, by default, cookies are visible to *(and modifiable by!)* the user.  With session variables, the client can't directly mess with them; it never sees anything but a session ID. With cookies, you lose that assurance; a semi-knowledgeable user can easily view and manipulate data your average PHP developer would have thought was private.